# Tap on iOS status bar to scroll back to top

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

When using `overflow-scroll="true"` on ion-content, after tapping the status bar it scrolls up and gets stuck - can't scroll down.

What to do? can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Documented issue at https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-v1/issues/155 (apparently still an issue as of now and some reporting it in V2 as well). For my case, I removed `overflow-scroll="true"` and replaced with css `overflow-y: scroll!important;` on my container and it solved the issue.